# GDB issue BFD: reopening /tmp/ .. : No such file or directory

Tags: gdb

I am running GDB on a Linux process and I find this whenever a breakpoint is hit.

GDB issue BFD: reopening /tmp/ .. : No such file or directory

I see a bug opened but not sure if someone knows solution to this.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14202

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that gdb lazily loads some sections, but you have deleted the shared library.

One fix is not to delete the shared library while gdb is using it.

Another fix is to modify gdb not to lazily load sections.  If you go this route, the lazy loading is all done in dwarf2read.c.